# Rank of Logistic Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I've built a logistic regression model in R using below lines of code. I tried extracting an element of model object called rank. How is this rank calculated internally?

```
fit = glm(vs ~ hp + mpg, mtcars, family = "binomial")
fit$rank # returns 3
```

Is it simply 1 more than number of independent variables?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `glm`

> `rank`  the numeric rank of the fitted linear model.

This is likely the rank of the design matrix.  Since you have 3 parameters to estimate (hp, mpg, and the intercept), and the two covariates are not perfectly collinear, the design matrix has rank 3.

It is not the number of independent variables.  For a single categorical variable with $c$ categories, the rank would be $c$.  In general, and assuming there is no perfect collinearity, the rank would be 1 + the number of continuous covariates + $\sum_{i=1}(c_i -1)$.  Here $c_i$ is the number of categories in the $i^{th}$ categorical variable included in the model.  We subtract one because one category is absorbed as the reference group.